# FB bot PSID retrieval during Account Linking

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I need some guidance on how to retrieve the Page Scope ID (PSID) or Sender ID while going through the Account Linking process.

The documentations suggested the following solution but I don't see how this can fit into my POST method or anywhere in my codes so that I can link my unique company ID with the PSID/Sender ID.

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN \
      &fields=recipient \
      &account_linking_token=ACCOUNT_LINKING_TOKEN"
```

Btw what is the **recipient** value above referring to?

APPRECIATE your help!

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below process to get the PSID (sender.id) through account linking

**Step 1** : Initiate the login process by sending the button to user from your bot

```
function sendAccountLinking(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
          template_type: "button",
          text: "Welcome. Link your account.",
          buttons: [{
            type: "account_link",
            url: SERVER_URL + "/authorize"
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}
```

**Step 2:** : Have a get method in your server code to and get the account_linking_token and redirect_uri request params.

for e.g :

```
/*
 * This path is used for account linking. The account linking call-to-action
 * (sendAccountLinking) is pointed to this URL. 
 * 
 */
app.get('/authorize', function (req, res) {
  console.log('%%%%%%%% AccountLinking Testing');
  var accountLinkingToken = req.query.account_linking_token;
  var redirectURI = req.query.redirect_uri;

  console.log('%%%%%%%% /authorize called with accountLinkingToken %s, redirectURI %s', accountLinkingToken, redirectURI);

  // Authorization Code should be generated per user by the developer. This will 
  // be passed to the Account Linking callback.
  var authCode = "1234567890";

  // Redirect users to this URI on successful login
  var redirectURISuccess = redirectURI + "&authorization_code=" + authCode;

  res.render('authorize', {
    accountLinkingToken: accountLinkingToken,
    redirectURI: redirectURI,
    redirectURISuccess: redirectURISuccess
  });
});
```

**Step 3:** : Use this account_linking_token and make the GET call to get the PSIN (sender.id) from your get method.

for e.g. httep.get call from your

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?access_token=YOUR_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=recipient&account_linking_token=ACCOUNT_LINKING_TOKEN

Response will be like :
 { "recipient": "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }

where receipient is the PSID(sender.id) and id is the appID (pageid)

Thanks,
Nagendra Prasad SBR.